# only "from" as abbreviation to indicate the origin

Tags: grammar, prepositions, abbreviations

After reading some publications that used "from" quite squishy, I would like to know:
Is it generally possible to use "from" instead of "produced using", "produced by" or as a short version of "derived/obtained from", especially when the number of words is limited (for example in titles or legends)?

For example:

1. Drugs produced by Company X = Drugs from Company X
2. Drugs obtained from Company Y = Drugs from Y
3. Drugs produced using enzymes  = Drugs from enzymes
4. Drugs derived from herbs = Drugs from herbs

All of them somehow seem legit to me if the context is known. But is it in principle ok to abbreviate in this way?

Comment: 1 & 2 are OK, but the use of 'from' in 3 & 4 is probably subject to government regulations about what exactly the term means.

Comment: Prepositions are little words with big jobs and many uses. You can't expect them to always mean the same thing; most of the time they don't have any meaning at all -- they're just required by some verb or noun or adjective or syntactic construction.

Comment: If enzymes are the _means_ rather than the _raw materials_ used to produce a pharmaceutical, then _from_ won't work.

Comment: thank you all for your comments. @KarlG I agree with you. But let's say means, such as enzymes, become kind of "humanised" as the research goes along, or in other words, as a result of a personal connection to the research object.  In this case, enzymes, for example, often aren't really thought of as means anymore but as a creator instead. Would it then work? Maybe this is getting too philosophical/psychological now, but I could already witness it many times among my scientist colleagues and I myself tend to humanise my precious means from time to time :-)